# How can I get minimum value in two dimensional array for given index?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

```
double[] tab = new double[10];
```

I know I can gen minimum by `tab.Min()`.

```
double[,] tab = new double[10,2];
```

This is table of coordinates, in 2nd index 0 is x and 1 is y. There are 10 points.

How can I get minimum (and maximum) value of x and y?

In other words:

`minX` is the smallest value in 1st column (second index=0 e.g `tab[xxx, 0]`);
`minY` is the smallest value in 2nd column (second index=1 e.g `tab[xxx, 1]`);

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to get.  You want the smallest pair (x,y) -- i.e., closest to the origin or are you trying to get the boundaries of the region -- min/max in each coordinate?

Comment: Point[] tab = new Point[10];  That's an array of coordinates.

Comment: @tvanfosson No he wants to get the minimum of a column.

Comment: @Jani - why do you say that?  He says he wants *minimum (and maximum) value of x and y*.  I'm just not sure whether he wants the length of each vector or is looking for the vectors with the min/max components in x and y.

Comment: Seems that I didn't understand it completely, lets wait till the OP clarify about what he wants

Comment: I want minimum/maximum in each column. 1st column is x, 2nd is y. I know Point[] is table of coordinates, but I prefer to use double[,]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var doubles = new double[4,2]{{1,2},{4,5},{7,8},{9,1}};
var min = System.Linq.Enumerable.Range(0, 4).Select(i => doubles[i, 1]).Min();
```

OR

```
var doubles = new double[4,2]{{1,2},{4,5},{7,8},{9,1}};
var min = System.Linq.Enumerable.Range(0, doubles.GetUpperBound(0)+1)
                                .Select(i => doubles[i, 1]).Min();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double minX = tab[0,0], minY = tab[0,1];
String coordinate = "X";

foreach (double number in tab)
{
    if (coordinate == "X")
    {
        if(number < minX)
            minX = number;

        coordinate = "Y";
    }
    else if (coordinate == "Y")
    {
        if (number < minY)
            minY = number;

        coordinate = "X";
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `string coordinade` I would use `int index=0` and change it later to `1`. I wanted to do this in similiar way to `tab.Min()`. I want that I can check each element in search for minimum.